Facing issues in getting Kong container up properly in google cloud shell
Hey there I am new to Kong, facing problem in getting Kong service up. I am using this repo's compose file, the problem is, everything gets up, like Network, Volumes, kong-db, kong, kong-migrations, kong-migrations-up, but the Kong UI isn't getting its configuration from Database or volumes. attaching a reference image
.
Although the same compose file works flawlessly on my local machine.
I tried different techniques like allowing all routes to get access to Kong.

Have you checked logs ?
